# Programmatically added gradientLayer does not clip to UIView added through Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, gradient

1. I have a prototype cell where I set a UIView in the back to have a solid background color (blue, to see the content clearly in Storyboard).

[image]

2. Then I decided to make this background color a gradient at some point (all in prototypeCell class):

   ```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        gradientBGView()
    }

    fileprivate func gradientBGView() {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.cornerRadius = 15
        gradient.frame = bgColorView.bounds //bgColorView is the UIView set in the @IBOutlet
        gradient.colors = [
            UIColor(red: 0.15, green: 0.19, blue: 0.22, alpha: 1.00).cgColor,
            UIColor(red: 0.39, green: 0.45, blue: 0.51, alpha: 1.00).cgColor ]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.2)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.8)
        bgColorView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
        bgColorView.layer.cornerRadius = 15 // this was done to make the solid color completely hide behind the gradient. I may as well get rid of this solid color altogether in the very end
    }
   ```

It all works fine in the portrait mode:

[image]

But as soon as you rotate your simulator to landscape mode, it seems that the solid background stretches out as planned (I pinned it to all sides in Storyboard), but the gradient remains the same, even though I have:

```
gradient.frame = bgColorView.bounds
```

**How do I force the gradient layer to stretch out like the solid color? How do I pin this gradient to UIView solid color's bounds properly?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layers do not auto-size with the view.

Add this simple `UIView` subclass to your project:

```
class GradientView: UIView {
    
    var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer!
    
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        gradientLayer = self.layer as? CAGradientLayer

        // if you are using these properties as constants,
        //  you can set them here
        gradientLayer.cornerRadius = 15
        gradientLayer.colors = [
            UIColor(red: 0.15, green: 0.19, blue: 0.22, alpha: 1.00).cgColor,
            UIColor(red: 0.39, green: 0.45, blue: 0.51, alpha: 1.00).cgColor
        ]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.2)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.8)

    }
    
}
```

Then, in your Storyboard Prototype cell, set the Custom Class of your `bgColorView` to `GradientView` (make sure to change your `@IBOutlet` connection as well):

```
@IBOutlet var bgColorView: GradientView!
```

If you may have different values for the colors and start/end points, you can also set them at run-time. For example, in `cellForRowAt`:

```
cell.gradientLayer.colors = [
     UIColor(red: 0.15, green: 0.19, blue: 0.22, alpha: 1.00).cgColor,
     UIColor(red: 0.39, green: 0.45, blue: 0.51, alpha: 1.00).cgColor
]
cell.gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.2)
cell.gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.8)
```

Now, when the cell frame changes, your `bgColorView` frame will change (because you have it constrained to the cell's contentView), and the gradient frame will size along with it.